Agora Flutter: Other Users Can't See or Hear a Viewer After Role Change to Participant
I am implementing a live streaming feature using the Agora SDK in a Flutter application. There are three types of roles in my app: VIEWER, PARTICIPANT, and HOST.
When users join the channel with their initial roles, everything works perfectly—audio and video streams function as expected for all roles. However, when a user changes their role from VIEWER to PARTICIPANT during the session, the following issue occurs:
Expected Behavior
After a role change from VIEWER to PARTICIPANT, other users in the channel (both HOST and PARTICIPANT) should be able to hear the new PARTICIPANT's audio and see their video stream.
Actual Behavior
The role change succeeds, and I can see the onUserJoined callback for the new PARTICIPANT on the HOST's side.
The PARTICIPANT's local video preview works for themselves.
However, other users in the channel cannot hear the PARTICIPANT's audio or see their video stream.
Code Example
Here’s a summary of the relevant implementation:
Initialization and Joining the Channel
await engine.initialize(const RtcEngineContext(appId: Constants.appId));
await engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfileType.channelProfileLiveBroadcasting);
await engine.enableVideo();
await engine.joinChannel(
  token: token!,
  channelId: roomId,
  uid: myUid.value,
  options: ChannelMediaOptions(
    autoSubscribeAudio: true,
    autoSubscribeVideo: true,
    publishCameraTrack: joinType.value != "VIEWER",
    publishMicrophoneTrack: joinType.value != "VIEWER",
  ),
);
await engine.setClientRole(
  role: joinType.value == "VIEWER"
      ? ClientRoleType.clientRoleAudience
      : ClientRoleType.clientRoleBroadcaster,
);

Role Change Logic (VIEWER to PARTICIPANT)
await engine.setClientRole(
  role: ClientRoleType.clientRoleBroadcaster,
  options: const ClientRoleOptions(
    audienceLatencyLevel: AudienceLatencyLevelType.audienceLatencyLevelUltraLowLatency,
  ),
);

await engine.enableAudio();
await engine.enableVideo();
await engine.muteLocalAudioStream(false);
await engine.muteLocalVideoStream(false);
await engine.startPreview();

for (var user in remoteRenderers) {
  await engine.muteRemoteAudioStream(uid: user.id!, mute: false);
  await engine.muteRemoteVideoStream(uid: user.id!, mute: false);
}

Event Handling for Role Changes
engine.registerEventHandler(
  RtcEngineEventHandler(
    onClientRoleChanged: (connection, oldRole, newRole, newRoleOptions) {
      print("Role changed from $oldRole to $newRole");
    },
    onUserJoined: (RtcConnection connection, int remoteUid, int elapsed) {
      print("Remote user $remoteUid joined the channel");
    },
    onUserOffline: (RtcConnection connection, int remoteUid, UserOfflineReasonType reason) {
      print("Remote user $remoteUid left the channel");
    },
  ),
);

What I Have Tried

Ensured all streams are unmuted: I used muteLocalAudioStream(false)
and muteLocalVideoStream(false) after the role change to make sure
the PARTICIPANT's streams are enabled.
Forced subscription for remote users: After the role change, I
explicitly called muteRemoteAudioStream and muteRemoteVideoStream for
other users in the channel to make sure their streams are active.
Checked event handlers: The onClientRoleChanged and onUserJoined
callbacks are firing as expected, but the issue persists.
Set appropriate media options: During joinChannel and role changes, I
verified that publishCameraTrack and publishMicrophoneTrack were
correctly set based on the user's role.

Questions

Is there a specific step required after changing roles from VIEWER to
PARTICIPANT to ensure that the PARTICIPANT's audio/video streams are
visible to other users in the channel?
Are there any specific Agora SDK settings or methods I might be
overlooking that are necessary for dynamic role changes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if more details or code snippets are required.
